# what is the syntax error in the line

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
<div ng-repeat="r in vm.GetRequests() | filter: vm.SearchText | orderBy:['LastName','FirstName']">
```

is there any syntax error in the above line ,because when I run it it gives me syntax Exception

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>   div[ng-repeat='r in vm.GetRequests() | filter: vm.SearchText |
>   orderBy:['LastName','FirstName']']

Error comes only in Chrome

Comment: The actual exception would be really helpful...

Comment: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: div[ng-repeat='r in vm.GetRequests() | filter: vm.SearchText | orderBy:['LastName','FirstName']']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works perfectly fine, but maybe the demo below helps you to get rid of the issue. I also tested it with a way older angular version.

```js
angular.module('testApp', [])

.controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
  var people = [{
      FirstName: 'John',
      LastName: 'Rambo'
    }, {
      FirstName: 'John',
      LastName: 'Rambo 2'
    }, {
      FirstName: 'Silvester',
      LastName: 'Stallone'
    }, {
      FirstName: 'Chuck',
      LastName: 'Norris'
    }
  ];

  $scope.vm = {
    SearchText: 'John',
    GetRequests: function() {
      return people;
    }

  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="r in vm.GetRequests() | filter: vm.SearchText | orderBy:['LastName','FirstName']">
    {{r.FirstName}} {{r.LastName}}
  </div>
</div>
```